# Parse optional arguments with multiple space-separated values for some arguments in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that should accept the following ways of specification:

```
./script.sh first second third
./script.sh --prefix pre --suffixes first second third --something
./scripts.sh -p pre -s first second third --something-else
```

The third way is the same as the second (just short). The second way is internally translated into `./script.sh pre.first pre.second pre.third` and the `--something` option is there because it controls some internal flow. What I'm struggling with is how to deal with both cases. It's fairly simple to deal with optional arguments with zero or one value but I want the number to be variable (at least for `--suffixes`) and also allow people to use the first invocation.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might do something like:

```
SUFFIXES=()

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do

    case $1 in
    '-p'|'--prefix')
        shift
        PREFIX="$1"
        ;;

    '-s'|'--suffixes')
        ;;

    '--something')
        SOMETHING="whatever something is or flags."
        ;;

    *)
        if [ -n "${SOMETHING+x}" ]; then
            # Any possible "something" args.
            echo "Got one something arg: $1"
        else
            # no '--something' flagged. Must be a suffix...
            SUFFIXES+=($1)
        fi
        ;;

    esac

    shift
done

WHOLE=( "${SUFFIXES[@]/#/$PREFIX}" )

echo "Final result: ${WHOLE[*]}"
```

Tests:

```
./script first second third --something
Final result: first second third

./script --prefix pre --suffixes first second third --something
Final result: prefirst presecond prethird

./script -p pre -s first second third --something
Final result: prefirst presecond prethird
```

Tell me if it is what you need.

Comment: I just realized that the you cannot place `--something`` as the first argument though.

Comment: You can use `SOMETHING` as a flag and use `--something` anywhere. When another command is found, simply undefine `SOMETHING`.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to have an option take an unknown number of arguments (be it "0 or 1" or "0 or more" or "1 or more").  Consider this generic invocation:

```
$ do_stuff -q thing thing2         # -q takes no arguments
$ do_stuff -o output thing thing2  # -o takes one argument
$ do_stuff -z z1 z2 thing thing2   # -z takes any number of arguments
```

How do we know that `z2` goes with `-z` but `thing` doesn't?  (You can add a special `--z-stop` or similar, but what if the user wanted to pass that exact string to `-z`?)

In your case, you may have an out.  If it doesn't make sense to specify strings manually (as in your first command) and also via prefixes/suffixes (as in your second command), then you can simply say that `-s`/`--suffixes` takes 0 arguments but *changes the interpretation* of your positional parameters.  (Then, if it makes no sense to have `-p` without `-s`, you can make `-p`/`--prefix` be an option with a single (mandatory) argument and remove `-s` altogether.)